# como retornar a linha atual usando variavel mas retornar a linha que está sendo usada a variável PHP

Tags: php, variáveis

Por exemplo:

```
<?php
$linha = __LINE__;

echo "a linha atual é $linha <br>";
//deveria retornar "a linha atual é 4"

echo "a linha atual é $linha <br>";
//deveria retornar "a linha atual é 7"

?>
```

mas em todas as linhas que eu uso a variavel $linha retorna 2. Como retornar a linha em que a variavel se encontra?

Comment: `echo "a linha atual é ".__LINE__." <br>";`

Comment: Qual a finalidade de armazenar o número da linha? o comentário acima resolve o problema a principio.

Comment: eu preciso pegar um código de erro, e esse código vai ser a linha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu fiz isso e deu certo:

```
<?php
function __CODIGO_ERRO__(){
    $backtrace = debug_backtrace();
    $line = $backtrace[0]['line'];
    return "<div class='box-alert box-alert-top box-alert-erro'>
                <div class='box-alert-container'>
                    <span class='erroCOD' data-erro='".$line."'>Erro na execução da consulta. COD: (".$line.")</span>
                </div>
            </div>";
}

echo __CODIGO_ERRO__();
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

A forma mais fácil que encontrei para solucionar sui problema é através da função [`debug_backtrace();`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.debug-backtrace.php) ela retorna varias informações, porem para facilitar eu criei um função e toda vez que a chamar ela ira retornar a linha em questão:

```
<?php 

function line(){        
    $backtrace = debug_backtrace();
    $line = $backtrace[0]['line'];
    return $line;
}

echo line();

echo line();
```

Testa ai e vê é isso que precisa.

Answer (score -1):

Do jeito que você fez funcionou, mas não funciona assim:

```
<?php
function line(){
    $backtrace = debug_backtrace();
    $line = $backtrace[0]['line'];
    return $line;
}

define("__CODIGO_ERRO__", "
<div class='box-alert box-alert-top box-alert-erro'>
    <div class='box-alert-container'>
        <span class='erroCOD' data-erro='".line()."'>Erro na execução da consulta. COD: (".line().")</span>
    </div>
</div>
");

echo __CODIGO_ERRO__;
 ?>
```

Ele retorna que a linha é a 11, mas deveria ser a 16. Tem algum jeito disso dar certo?

Comment: Você sabe como funciona funções e chamada de funções em uma linguagem de programação? Se você chama a função para definir a constante `__CODIGO_ERRO__`, o valor da linha será referente a essa chamada. Toda vez que utilizar a constante, terá o mesmo valor (até porque é uma constante e constante não variam, geralmente).

Comment: ahh vlw, consegui